# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "User" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\praveenblog\includes\config.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\praveenblog\

Tags: php

Hi everyone please help me in this code i think i am doing something wrong unable to find mistake

i am getting error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "User" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\praveenblog\includes\config.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\praveenblog\admin\login.php(4): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\praveenblog\includes\config.php on line 43 please help in fixing this error

Config.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

//database details
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','praveenblogcms');

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


//set timezone- Asia Kolkata 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

//load classes as needed
function spl__autoload_register($class) {
   
   $class = strtolower($class);

    //if call from within assets adjust the path
   $classpath = 'classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
    }   
    
    //if call from within admin adjust the path
   $classpath = '../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
    }
    
    //if call from within admin adjust the path
   $classpath = '../../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
    }       
     
}

$User = new User($db); 

?>
```

class.user.php

```
<?php

class User{

    private $db;
    
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db; 
    }


    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }        
    }

    public function create_hash($value)
    {
        return $hash = crypt($value, '$2a$12.substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(sha1(microtime(true), true))), 0, 22)');


    }

    private function verify_hash($password,$hash)
    {
        return $hash == crypt($password, $hash);
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){    

        try {

            //echo $this->create_hash('demo');

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT password FROM praveen_blog_users WHERE username = :username');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
            
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="error">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    
    public function login($username,$password){    

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        
        if($this->verify_hash($password,$hashed) == 1){
            
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }        
    }
    
        
    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }
    
}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
//Your connection file 
require_once('../includes/config.php');


// user looged in or not 
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); } 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Admin Login</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="login">

<?php 

   //Login form for submit 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        
        if($user->login($username,$password)){ 

            //If looged in , the redirects to index page 
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        

        } else {
            $message = '<p class="invalid">Invalid username or Password</p>';
        }

    }

    if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }
?>

    <form action="" method="POST" class="form">
   <label>Username</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" value=""  required />
<br>
 <label>Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" value="" required />
<br>
    <label></label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SignIn"  />

    

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please support on this

Comment: `spl__autoload_register` looks like a typo? Should be `spl_autoload_register`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response changed that and tried no getting error

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in C:\xampp\htdocs\praveenblog\includes\config.php on line 38

Comment: I believe you're supposed to call that function, not redeclare it. Read the documentation and look at examples

Comment: thank you so much you are correct i was redeclaring its now fixed